# show that the function: $F(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|}$ satisfies $F\in C^1(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

> (a) For an open subset $E\subset R$ and $f\in C^1(E)$ show that the function: $F(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1+|f(x)|}$ satisfies $F\in C^1(E)$.
>   And that if $x_0\in E$ if $f(x_0)=0$ then $F^{'}(x_0)=f^{'}(x_0)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}F^{'}(x)=F^{'}(x_0)$.
>   (b) Then extend this result to $f\in C^{1}(E)$ for an open $E\subset R^n$

I managed to do the part (a) by the hint they have provided. That is to show that if $f(x)\neq 0$ then $F^{'}(x)=\frac{f^{'}(x)}{(1+|f(x)|)^2}$.
But how should I extend this to the $E\in R^n$.

First I thought $E=E_1\times E_2\times\cdot\cdot\cdot E_n$ where each $E_i\subset R$ is open. And then for $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ function $f :E\to R$ as
$f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x_i)$ where $f_i\in C^{1}(E_i)$.
But that didn't work because to prove

> if $x_0\in E$ if $f(x_0)=0$ then $F^{'}(x_0)=f^{'}(x_0)$ and 
>   $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}F^{'}(x)=F^{'}{(x_0)}$

We will not have $f(x_0)=0$ giving $f_i=0$.
Appreciate your help.
This is the exercise 3.1 from the book *Ordinary Differential Equation by L. Perko*

Answer (score 1):

Since part (a) is proved, you have in particular that the function
given by $g(x) = \frac{x}{1+|x|}$ is $C^1$. Then for part (b) observe
that $F = g\circ f$. Since $g$ and $f$ are $C^1$, it follows by the 
multivariable Chain Rule that $F$ is $C^1$.